# How to determine if an int is perfect square?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

My code seems to pass many cases, but my codes seem to fail a particular private test case. Can anyone help me ?

```
static boolean isSquare(int n) {
    IntStream y=IntStream.range(1, n).map(((int x)->{return x*x;}));
    return y.anyMatch(x->(x==n));
}
```

Comment: I believe 0 also qualifies as a perfect square by most definitions?

Comment: Can you share that test case?

Comment: Hi, the failed test case isn't shown because we are expected to figure out the mistakes ourself and not refer to the test case. But I don't see where my code has gone wrong.

Comment: Is it failing due to timeout?

Answer (score 1):

It fails for 1, because 1 also is a perfect square and your current code currently doesn't handle that scenario. Change your code to :

```
static boolean isSquare(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n).map(x -> x * x).anyMatch(x -> x == n);
}
```

Notice how we use `rangeClosed` instead of `range` which includes both upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Yes I realized my mistake wasn't accounting the fact that 0 is a perfect number too. Thank you everyone for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can watch what's happens using peek in your stream pipe line like this:

```
IntStream y=IntStream.range(1, n).map(((int x)->{return x*x;})).peek( System.out::println);
```

I thing that the problem can be that the range must be rangeClosed :

```
 static boolean isSquare(int n) {
    IntStream y=IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).map(((int x)->{return x*x;})).peek( System.out::println);
    return y.anyMatch(x->(x==n));
}
```

And also, it wont work with negative numbers.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: A negative number can not be a square number, so that’s irrelevant.